# How to loop through an ArrayList with XML?

Tags: java, arrays, xslt, arraylist

I am currently trying:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//asdf/@abc">
   <span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I saw in many forums that people can use the `.` to signify the array attribute, but it isn't working in my case.

To be clear, I am trying to avoid restructuring the DTO. How would you go about this?

Thanks!

---

*update*

Ok, part of my issue was a newbish knowledge of xml. I restructure how the xml was formed to get the appropriate nodes. But I still don't know how to xsl-ify them. Here is the xml:

```
<wrapper>
        <node>
            <one>one</two>
            <two>two</two>
            <three>three</three>
        </node>
</wrapper>
```

And all i want to do is display the three value. I am trying:

```
<xsl:value-of match="wrapper">
    <xsl:for-each select="node">
        <xsl:value-of select="three"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:value-of>
```

But it is bad syntax I think. If there are any fundamental concepts or simple tips to achieve this, any input would be awesome!

Thanks again.

---

*update*

To be clear, there are multiple nodes and the wrapper is itself nested:

```
<outerwrapper>
    <wrapper>
        <node>
            <one>one</two>
            <two>two</two>
            <three>three</three>
        </node>
        <node>
            <one>one</two>
            <two>two</two>
            <three>three</three>
        </node>
    </wrapper>
</outerwrapper>
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example (incl. input and the expected output)  - see: [mcve].

Comment: You have `<one>one</two>` in your XML - that's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

> But it is bad syntax I think.

Yes, it is. This part:

```
<xsl:value-of match="wrapper">
```

makes no sense. It should be:

```
<xsl:template match="wrapper">
```

Of course, you could shorten the whole thing to:

```
<xsl:template match="/wrapper">
    <xsl:value-of select="node/three"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ok, but the thing is, there are multiple nodes, and the way i am selecting the wrapper is like this: `<xsl:value-of select="//outerwrapper/@wrapper">`

Comment: @pward You were asked to provide a **complete** example. Don't be surprised if the answer doesn't fit the situation you did **not** tell us about. -- Right now I am confused because you have two (or more?) `<three>` nodes - and you did not tell us which one you want to select. In any case, the expression `//outerwrapper/@wrapper` will not select anything in your example.

Comment: No worries! I appreciate getting a response at all. Thank you!